# How to convert sql statements to json

Tags: python, sql, json

I was looking to [this website](https://www.csvjson.com/sql2json) which uses insert and create statements for getting the json structure. Is there any same way in python to convert sql queries having insert and create statements to json format.

Example: 
SQL query:

```
/**
 * Continents 
 */
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `continents`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `continents`;
CREATE TABLE `continents` (
  `code` char(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Continent code',
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of continents
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `continents` VALUES ('AF', 'Africa');
INSERT INTO `continents` VALUES ('AN', 'Antarctica');
INSERT INTO `continents` VALUES ('AS', 'Asia');
INSERT INTO `continents` VALUES ('EU', 'Europe');
INSERT INTO `continents` VALUES ('NA', 'North America');
INSERT INTO `continents` VALUES ('OC', 'Oceania');
INSERT INTO `continents` VALUES ('SA', 'South America');
INSERT INTO `continents` VALUES ('??', NULL);
```

JSON structure:

```
{
  "continents": [
    {
      "code": "AF",
      "name": "Africa"
    },
    {
      "code": "AN",
      "name": "Antarctica"
    },
    {
      "code": "AS",
      "name": "Asia"
    },
    {
      "code": "EU",
      "name": "Europe"
    },
    {
      "code": "NA",
      "name": "North America"
    },
    {
      "code": "OC",
      "name": "Oceania"
    },
    {
      "code": "SA",
      "name": "South America"
    },
    {
      "code": "??",
      "name": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: can't you read from SQL and then transform the read data into JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course it's possible - if someone came with a working implementation in a language, then it's possible with any turing-complete language.

Now you have two possible ways to tackle this. The first one is to write a full "SQL2json" parser/tokenizer/interpreter (you can read about programming languages implementation for more on how to do this) that will parse the SQL source code and generate the matching json text as result, or much more simply you can execute the SQL source against a database, then query the database with your python DB-API connector and generate a list of dicts from the query result (using a DictCursor will make it a breeze) and serialize it with the json module.